# Were these downvotes automatic?

Tags: support, down-votes

I just glanced at my [profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/7048/craige?tab=reputation&StartDate=2012-04-24) a moment ago and noticed a significant stream of 20 downvotes on answers all within the same 1 minute.

Could these be automatic, or simply a malicious user with a grudge?

Comment: 19 DVs in less than an hour, for a bunch of totally different answers, well... if this is not a [serial downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial-downvotes "MSO officially has a tag for that") then I don't know what is

Comment: The down votes were reversed once the bot run, and the culprit was contacted privately. On a personal note I absolutely hate revenge down voters and can't promise I will resist the urge to go mod crazy next time (to whom it may concern).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They'll probably be malicious, however, don't worry about them. There are automatic processes that spot this sort of thing and reverse serial up votes and serial down votes.

If the votes are still there tomorrow morning (UTC) then let us know and we'll take it up with the development team.

Comment: Good to know. I'll check back in tomorrow if it doesn't clear up. Thank's for the information.